# Does POSIX ls -R dictate a specific traversal order? If not, then which assumption is more likely to be portable: depth-first or breadth-first?

Tags: algorithm, posix, ls, gnu-coreutils

I'm working on a system that stores something very similar to a file system's inode tree.  It already has an equivalent of the `ls` command, but it does not yet support a recursive option.  I'm investigating implementation choices for adding the recursive option.  I'd like to maximize familiarity for users that know POSIX `ls` and maximize portability for any scripts written to consume the output of POSIX `ls -R`.

It seems `ls -R` could be implemented with either depth-first traversal or breadth-first traversal.  However, I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on whether a particular traversal order is dictated by specification or if it's left as an implementation choice.

In the [POSIX documentation for `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/ls.html), I cannot find any specific answer.  This is the only statement I could find related to the implementation of the recursion:

> Implementations are expected to traverse arbitrary depths when processing the -R option. The only limitation on depth should be based on running out of physical storage for keeping track of untraversed directories.

I also tried reviewing the documentation for [`nftw`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html).  Again, I found no specific statement of the traversal order there.

For some empirical measurement, I ran a test on a CentOS box, and the behavior there is clearly depth-first traversal.

```
> uname -a
Linux centos 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> yum info coreutils
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.pac-12.org
 * elrepo: ftp.osuosl.org
 * epel: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: ftp.osuosl.org
Installed Packages
Name        : coreutils
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 8.22
Release     : 11.el7
Size        : 14 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : anaconda
Summary     : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/
License     : GPLv3+
Description : These are the GNU core utilities.  This package is the combination of
            : the old GNU fileutils, sh-utils, and textutils packages.

> tree testTraversal/
testTraversal/
├── dir1
│   └── dir8
│       └── dir9
│           └── dir10
├── dir2
│   ├── dir4
│   │   └── dir5
│   ├── dir6
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── dir3
└── dir4
    └── dir5
        └── dir6
            └── dir7
                ├── file3
                ├── file4
                └── file5

> ls -R testTraversal/
testTraversal/:
dir1/  dir2/  dir3/  dir4/

testTraversal/dir1:
dir8/

testTraversal/dir1/dir8:
dir9/

testTraversal/dir1/dir8/dir9:
dir10/

testTraversal/dir1/dir8/dir9/dir10:

testTraversal/dir2:
dir4/  dir6/  file1  file2

testTraversal/dir2/dir4:
dir5/

testTraversal/dir2/dir4/dir5:

testTraversal/dir2/dir6:

testTraversal/dir3:

testTraversal/dir4:
dir5/

testTraversal/dir4/dir5:
dir6/

testTraversal/dir4/dir5/dir6:
dir7/

testTraversal/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7:
file3  file4  file5
```

I don't know if this is behavior dictated by spec or just an implementation detail of GNU coreutils.

My own observation is that directory structures in a file system tend to be wider than they are deep.  That would indicate that depth-first is generally the more memory-efficient implementation choice, although it is possible to come up with counter-examples where breadth-first would be more memory-efficient.

Is the traversal order dictated anywhere in the specs?  If not, then is depth-first traversal widely used in implementation, and therefore a safer assumption than breadth-first?

Comment: `nftw()` has `FTW_DEPTH` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[coreutils](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/coreutils/src/ls.c#queue_directory) is indeed depth first. [busybox](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#busybox/coreutils/ls.c#L1055) is depth first. BSD/OS X is depth first (experimentally; the source is unreadable). I would expect most implementations to be depth first, because it's easy to do recursively and because the POSIX limit on path lengths bounds the memory/stack usage of depth first traversal pretty tightly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  At this point, it looks unlikely that we'll find a point in the specs that directly says "must be depth-first", but the argument that it's the practical choice makes sense.  I'll accept this answer.